# What tweak do I need to make ssh://user@machine.com URL work with fish on iterm2 in mac?

Tags: macos, ssh, fish, iterm2

I was using bash before and it worked when I clicked ssh://user@machine.com links from the browser. It will open iTerm2 (as I've set iTerm2 as the default handler for ssh links). Since I started using fish, this doesn't work anymore. Do I miss a setting somewhere perhaps in fish config?

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Preferences** -> **Profiles** -> **Default** profile (profile with a star) -> **URL Schemes** -> Select **ssh**.

**Note**:Switching Default profile might reset the conf.

Or third-party apps like [DefaultApps](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/Bundles.html#RCDefaultApp) can be used to set default apps for URL Schemes.